# How to include quote character in jenkinfile variable

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

How to include quote single and double quote  character in jenkinfile along with variable. I just need to print CURLDATA variable from my jenkinfile.

My Jenkinsfile look like this -

```
{
    def CURLDATA = "\'{\"to\":\"${MEETINGROOM}\", \"type\":\"meeting\", \"from\":\"absEMbot@myapplication.att.com\", \"password\":\"${ROOMPASS}\", \"displayfromname\":\"ABS EM Bot\", \"html\":\"BUILD FAILURE:${ENVIRONMENT}\"}\'"

sh "echo CurlData is : ${CURLDATA}"  

}
```

Below is the error i get in jenkin console -

org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 60: Expected a step @ line 60, column 13.
               def CURLDATA = "\'{\"to\":\"${MEETINGROOM}\", \"type\":\"meeting\", \"from\":\"absEMbot@myapplication.att.com\", \"password\":\"${ROOMPASS}\", \"displayfromname\":\"ABS EM Bot\", \"html\":\"BUILD FAILURE:${ENVIRONMENT}\"}\'"
               ^

1 error

Can someone tell me how to resolve it. Tried lots of other ways too.

---

This one works in Jenkins Script Console

```
{
    def MEETINGROOM = "Test"
    def CURLDATA = "\'{\"to\":\"${MEETINGROOM}\"}\'"
    println  "${CURLDATA}"
  }
```

Result
'{"to":"Test"}'

But the same thing didnot work from jenkinfile.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the multiline string """ here so you dont have to escape ' or "

```
{
  def MEETINGROOM = "Test"
  def CURLDATA = """'{"to":"${MEETINGROOM}"}'"""
  println  "${CURLDATA}"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reponse- Still getting same error -org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 60: Expected a step @ line 60, column 13.
               def CURLDATA = """'{"to":"${MEETINGROOM}", "type":"meeting", "from":"absEMbot@myapplication.att.com", "password":"${ROOMPASS}", "displayfromname":"ABS EM Bot", "html":"BUILD FAILURE:${ENVIRONMENT}"}'"""
               ^

1 error

Comment: do you use a declarative pipeline or a scripted?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`/slashy string/`](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_slashy_string):

```
def CURLDATA = /'{"to":"Test"}'/
```

Also you need to wrap assignments in a `script` step:

```
script {
    def CURLDATA = /'{"to":"Test"}'/
    echo "${CURLDATA}"
}
```

Comment: These works perfectly on groovy but NOT on the jenkin pipeline (jenkinfile)-org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 61: Expected a step @ line 61, column 13.
               CURLDATA = /'{"to":"${MEETINGROOM}"}'/
               ^

1 error. Let me know if anyone has the Pipeline syntax.

Comment: Oh, I see. You need to wrap it all in a `script` step. Will update the answer.